# Windows Service stalling

Tags: c#, windows-services, google-calendar-api, xdebug

I have a windows service that is supposed to run at certain intervals (currently set at 1 minute for testing purposes) and acquire data from our data base and then upload the information to our Google Calendar. Within debug mode everything runs fine, however when the windows service runs by itself on my PC it seems to be stalling at the "Inside StartGoogleCalendar" EventLog entry. Why would it run just fine in Debug mode but stall when it is in production mode? Am I doing something wrong? Below is the code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Service Started: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1 * 60 * 1000);
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fireGoogle);
    _timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Service Stopped: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
}

private void fireGoogle(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Firing Google: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
    StartGoogleCalendar();
}

public void StartGoogleCalendar()
{
    try
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Inside StartGoogleCalendar");
        authorization Auth = new authorization();
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Done with Auth");
        calendar ipamCal = new calendar();
        EventLog.WriteEntry(Auth.EventLogEvent());
        EventLog.WriteEntry("GAPI Calendar Schedule complete");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Data.ToString() + ": INNER EXCEPTION: " + ex.InnerException.ToString() + " - GENERAL MESSAGE: " + ex.Message.ToString() + " - SOURCE: " + ex.Source.ToString() );
    }
}
```

Here is the "authorization" code (client_secrets.json does exist, as it does work in debug mode):

```
    private static EventLog _el = new EventLog();
    public authorization()
    {
        globals.scopes = new List<string>();
        _authCredentials();
    }

    private void _authCredentials()
    {
        globals.scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");

        try
        {
            _el.WriteEntry("Inside _authcredentials");
            using (FileStream _stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                _el.WriteEntry("Attempting to get credentials");
                globals.userCredentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(_stream).Secrets, globals.scopes, "Today-at-IPAM", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("calendar_new.dat")).Result;
                _el.WriteEntry(globals.userCredentials.Token.ToString());
            }

            _el.WriteEntry( "Google Authorization - SUCCESS");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { _el.WriteEntry( "Google Authorization - FAILED\r\n\tReason: " + ex.InnerException.Message); }
    }

    public String EventLogEvent()
    { return globals.eventLogEvents; }
```

Comment: what is your Authorization code doing?

Comment: Added code for authorization as per your request, please take a look

Comment: FileDatastore stores a file called calendar_new.dat in your %appData% directory for you.  Did you set the windows service to run as your user account?  It may not have access to it. I normally use a service account when something is going to be run though windows service.

Comment: The windows service is set to use Local System Account and the serviceprocessinstaller Account property is set to LocalService

Comment: When you run it the debug environment it popped up and asked you to authorize it.  This saved your authorization in your %appData% directory.  Your windows service is not going to have access to that.  If you don't understand I suggest we move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58744/discussion-between-mattgcon-and-daimto).

Comment: @DaImTo I think maybe we should take this into chat if you have some time. I need to figure this out and it appears you know what you are speaking of. I am setting log on account to my user account but it still seams to be stalling at the same place

Comment: check your projet's property, in that look wether you are building your project for (32-bit/64-bit) system. I think that can help you.

Comment: It's likely that your `catch` block is throwing a null reference exception on `ex.InnerException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue had to do with the .dat file becoming invalid due to google authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You must test several things :
1/ When you have add the service in windows system have you specified the entire path of execution 
Please refer with the command line. 
SC CREATE "ServiceName" DisplayName= "Displaying Service Name" binpath= "C:\User\Service.exe" start= auto obj= "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"

2 / What is the account that you use to launch of the service, the permissions are right ?
please refer the parameter obj on the previous exemple.

3 / What is permissions of the directory and the file "client_secrets.json"

Answer (score 1):

When you run service in debug mode it will look for the files in bin folder of your service executable. but when you run it in release mode i.e. as an installed service, it runs via service control manager for which working folder is system32. fist thing you should do is put the path to your secrets file in .config file and then read that path to load the file via absolute path to file (client_secrets.json).

secondly i would not suggest to write everything in windows event log. you should consider using log4net or similar for application logging.

and finally your timer is asyn timer at the moment, imagine if your process takes longer than your timer interval it will execute another request before first one finishes. you should consider making your timer synchronous

Answer (score 1):

People's suggestions to look at the permissions relating to your service look valid.
I would add that your both of your catch statements can fail. What happens if there is no innerException? :)

I'm not familiar with google's authentiation module - but if you can target a more specific exception first that might help you get to the bottom of why your service is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things:

a) check if the account running the service has sufficient permission to access internet.

b) I would create a separate thread and do the work there. For example:

```
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private Thread _thread;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
            _thread.Start();
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            // Write your code here...
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test123.txt","hello world!");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
```

Basically, we should not do long running tasks in side OnStart(). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, it may not be relative to your issue. 
I see that you are creating your authorization object every minute and adding same scope url to it. I don't know if your globals object gets cleared or not, you may have some kind of thread issues opening web request connection.
Same is true, you are adding over and over same credentials.

Convert your authorization object to singleton and see if it will work or don't use globals and clean up your object when it's going out of scope.

I had similar issue with some automated calls to web from window (not window service) where it had thread raising issues and would hang.

2c, Usually it is not a good idea to call any functions from object constructor.